# Automatically run the same request for every id in a JSON file in Postman

Tags: json, postman

I would like to have Postman automatically make the same delete API call for all of the Ids listed in a JSON file since the API I am using does not allow multi-delete.

Something like:
`http://testing.com/api/product/{{Id}}`

I have a list of ids in the following json format:

```
[{
  "name": "Prod 1",
  "id": 14324
},
{
  "name": "Prod 2",
  "id": 32424
},
{
  "name": "Prod 3",
  "id": 45645
}]
```

How can I go about running something that will run the same request for every id in the JSON list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is possible using the Collection Runner. An explanation can be found in the documentation: [Working with data files](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/)

In short:

1. Store your JSON into a `.json` file.
2. Make sure your request is part of a collection.
3. Add the JSON property key (`id` in your case) as a variable to your URL like you did in your example URL: `http://testing.com/api/product/{{id}}`

   - (Make sure the casing of the variable matches the one in your JSON file.)
4. Click on the "Runner" button in the top left of Postman to open the Collection Runner.
5. On the left select the collection and on the right check the request you want to run.
6. Click on the "Select File" after the "Data" option and select your JSON file.
7. Hit "Preview" below to see if the JSON is interpreted correctly.
8. At the "Iterations" option enter the number of objects you have in your JSON.

   - (In your sample that would be 3)
9. Hit "Run [Collection name]".

At that point Postman should repeat the request for the amount entered in the "Iterations" option and for each iteration replace your `{{id}}` in the URL with the `id` in your JSON for that iteration.

[image: Images showing the options in the Collection Runner]

Comment: thank you so much for the response! I believe this is going to work however I am getting an error in my JSON syntax for some reason.. Can I pass it a list exactly as in my example (I fixed the commas). Or do I need to put them all in an array and wrap with out level tags? I am getting an error the json must be in an array.

Comment: I am trying with a JSON file exactly as in my example and it keeps saying "Unexpected token at position 23".

Comment: You need to wrap them in an array. So your JSON would be `[{"name": "Prod 1", "id": 14324}, {"name": "Prod 2", "id": 32424}, {"name": "Prod 3", "id": 45645}]`.

Comment: just realized that when downloading the sample in the documentation you linked. Thank you so much!